# Error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::shared_ptr<uint8_t []>'

Tags: android, android-ndk, c++17

I am trying to use `std::shared_ptr <uint8_t []>` in my NDK application, but compiler throws below error.

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of '`std::shared_ptr<uint8_t []>`'

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> x_data(new uint8_t[bytes_to_send]);
```

My NDK version is r19c and the CMake looks like below

```
cmake {

           version "3.10.2"

          cppFlags "-std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -frtti -fexceptions"
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the libc++ [Feature Test Macro Support page](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/FeatureTestMacroTable.html), the `__cpp_lib_shared_ptr_arrays` feature is currently unimplemented.

It may have something to do with [this task](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0414r2.html) not having been started according to [this page](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html).

---

An alternative in the meantime might be to explicitly specify an array deleter:

```
std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> x_data(new uint8_t[bytes_to_send], std::default_delete<uint8_t[]>());
```

(as seen in the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete))

Comment: Thank You for the clear input. Please refer https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/950 for more details